# The jquery.d.ts definition is generating many errors in TypeScript 0.9

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, when include `jquery.d.ts` getting many syntax errors while building the code, I'm using VS express 2012. To include the jQuery definition I have use the following code:

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts" />
```

I get a lot of errors just from the definition file - such as this:

```
Error   109 Index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.    D:/Able/TypeScript/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/jquery.d.ts    54  20  HelloWorld
```

Here is the screen shot of error...

[image]

Why is the definition file generating errors?

Comment: Can you show us that line so we can help?

Comment: may I know why this question is off-topic?

Comment: @SteveFenton I'm getting the error when compile the code, do I need to post the jQuery file code?

Comment: Where did you get the `jquery.d.ts` file from?

Comment: https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/92d9e637f6e1#typings/jquery.d.ts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32871/discussion-between-delphian-and-steve-fenton)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TypeScript definition you have won't work in the TypeScript 0.9 compiler.

You can get the latest version from either...

[Codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#typings/jquery.d.ts) or [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery)

You'll notice that the indexers are updated from:

```
headers?: { [key: any]: any; };
```

To

```
headers?: { [key: string]: any; };
```

This is to comply with tighter compiler rules that state the key must be a string or a number.

Comment: Great help and support. Thank You. You are awesome :)